# STM32 - update firmware from data stored in SRAM

Tags: stm32, ota, stm32cubeide

I would like to remotely update the firmware of my STM32WLE5 device. I can transfer the new binary file from the server to the STM's SRAM using my custom link only, which means I cannot utilize other native update procedures provided by STM, such as UART. However, I'm unsure about what steps to take with the data once it's in the SRAM.

Does anyone know how to update the firmware using the data stored in the SRAM?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the bootloader and startup code in embedded systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696258/what-is-the-bootloader-and-startup-code-in-embedded-systems)

Comment: You need to learn how to write the bootloader

Comment: You'll need to carefully consider what would happen if the board was to be powered down or reset during an update. You'll probably find that you need to store two copies of your code in the flash (the runnable one, and the update one), and use checksums and version numbers to manage which one should be run (or if one should be copied over the other). But yes, as another comment said, you're going to need some kind of bootloader.